# How to allow save duplicate keys in sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I want to add duplicate keys on database. Presently it shows error while inserting duplicate key.

How can I insert duplicate keys into database?

My insertion query is

```
 string qry = "insert into EmpMaster values('"id+"','"+code+"','"+type+"','"+fname+"')";
 SqlDataReader dr1 = conn.query(qry);.
```

Primary key is `code`.

Comment: You can turn off a PK constraint on the table, but I would advise against it

Comment: Take on extra column which will be used inplace of your current id column

Comment: Why do you need duplicate keys?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert duplicate to primary key column. Primary key is for not null and non-duplicate values to do so remove primary key column name from code. or take another column which can insert duplicate

Suggestion :- Removing primary key is not a good practice. If you want to add duplicate keys then you can use another column

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add duplicate to a primary key column. 
If you want to add duplicate data in **COLUMN "CODE"**, just normalize your database and make *foreign key references* .